# Parsing fix width file using nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am very new to [NiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_NiFi) and trying to solve the following scenario:

I have a fixed width file in the following format:

```
AAAAAxbnkdf      fg kjsdkgghjkg  
CCCCCjljdsjglg  gjg dkljgllkjds  
EEEEEEkljdfgkd jksf sbgjsdljkga  
AAAAAxbnkdfsfg grgh kjsdkgghjkg  
CCCCCjljdsjgl  jdjd jgdkljglsds
```

I want to scan each line of the file and check for lines starting with `AAAAA` or `CCCCC`. The output should be three different flow files where the first file should contain all the lines starting with `AAAAA`, the second file should contain all the lines starting with `CCCCC` and the third flow file should contain all the other lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [RouteText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteText/index.html) processor.  You will need to do a bit of configuration and add dynamic properties for the `'AAAAA'` and `'CCCCC'` lines:

- **Routing Strategy**: Route to each matching Property Name
- **Matching Strategy**: Starts With
- **AAAAA**: AAAAA
- **CCCCC**: CCCCC

After making these changes, the processor will have output relationships for `'AAAAA'`, `'CCCCCC'`, and 'unmatched' (for everything else).

Comment: James' answer is very good, but `RouteText` separates each line as an individual flowfile. If you want to aggregate the resulting flowfiles into collective ones, use a `MergeContent` processor following the `RouteText`.

Comment: @Andy, that wasn't my experience, despite the docs. I think with the settings above it will route all matching lines as one flowfile.

Comment: Thanks James. I'll investigate and update the documentation if necessary.